# How to find the version of the loaded driver of asr mobility agent?

Tags: windows, version, filter-driver, azure-site-recovery

I'm looking to find the version of asr mobility agent for windows (InDskFlt.sys) when it's loaded.

When upgrading the client the loaded driver is not changing - only after reboot to the machine, it's creating a situation that the loaded driver version is different from the .sys file version in drivers folder.

I found a way to query the loaded driver with an application inside asr installation folder called drvutil.exe (with --gdv parameter). can someone confirm that the app actually querying the loaded driver ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Indskflt is the driver used to track changes on the disk and and it has to unload the older version and load the new version, hence reboot us required after the reboot.

Kindly let us know if the above helps or you need further assistance on this issue.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but this does not answer the question. The question is if drvutil.exe util is querying the loaded driver that's in the memory.